# What to change for different report?

Tags: php

I need help, I am total Newbie in php. I buy code and it is not generating the report which I need. I have a peace of code with missing user Id in report. I could have wrote something but it will due to lack of my knowledge last forever...  I really appreciate your help.

There are few kind of `ID` in code... `USER ID`, `PACKET PALNS ID`, `ADS ID`,   `PAYMENT ID`... in final report depending on what user choose, system generate  bugged report with a) POINTS PLAN ID b) ADS ID and send to mail C) PAYMENT ID....I need to change the code that in all of these 3 kinds of reports have one more id - USER ID

```
   <?php
/**

* You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
* along with DJ Classifieds. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
* 
*/
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
jimport('joomla.event.plugin');
if(!defined("DS")){ define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);}
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('plg_djclassifiedspayment_djcfBankTransfer',JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);
require_once(JPATH_BASE.DS.'administrator'.DS.'components'.DS.'com_djclassifieds'.DS.'lib'.DS.'djnotify.php');


class plgdjclassifiedspaymentdjcfBankTransfer extends JPlugin
{
    function plgdjclassifiedspaymentdjcfBankTransfer( &$subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
        $this->loadLanguage('plg_djcfBankTransfer');
        $params["plugin_name"] = "djcfBankTransfer";
        $params["icon"] = "banktransfer_icon.jpg";
        $params["logo"] = "banktransfer_overview.jpg";
        $params["description"] = JText::_("PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_METHOD_DESC");
        $params["payment_method"] = JText::_("PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME");       
        $params["pay_info"] = $this->params->get("pay_info");
        $this->params = $params;

    }

    function onPaymentMethodList($val)
    {
        if($val["direct_payment"]){
            return null;
        }
        $type='';
        if($val['type']){
            $type='&type='.$val['type'];    
        }   
        $html ='';
        $user = JFactory::getUser();

        if($this->params["pay_info"]!=''){

        $paymentLogoPath = JURI::root()."plugins/djclassifiedspayment/".$this->params["plugin_name"]."/".$this->params["plugin_name"]."/images/".$this->params["logo"];
            //$form_action = JRoute :: _("index.php?option=com_djclassifieds&task=processPayment&ptype=".$this->params["plugin_name"]."&pactiontype=process&id=".$val["id"].$type, false);
            $form_action = JURI::root()."index.php?option=com_djclassifieds&task=processPayment&ptype=".$this->params["plugin_name"]."&pactiontype=process&id=".$val["id"].$type;
            $html ='<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                <tr>';
                    if($this->params["logo"] != ""){
                $html .='<td class="td1" width="160" align="center">
                        <img src="'.$paymentLogoPath.'" title="'.$this->params["payment_method"].'"/>
                    </td>';
                     }
                    $html .='<td class="td2">
                        <h2>'. $this->params["payment_method"].'</h2>
                        <p style="text-align:justify;">'.$this->params["description"].'</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="td3" width="130" align="center">
                        <a class="button" style="text-decoration:none;" href="'.$form_action.'">'.JText::_('COM_DJCLASSIFIEDS_BUY_NOW').'</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>';      

        }
        return $html;
    }   

    function onProcessPayment()
    {
        $ptype = JRequest::getVar('ptype','');
        $id = JRequest::getInt('id','0');
        $html="";



        if($ptype == $this->params["plugin_name"])
        {
            $action = JRequest::getVar('pactiontype','');
            switch ($action)
            {
                case "process" :
                $html = $this->process($id);
                break;
                case "notify" :
                $html = $this->_notify_url();
                break;
                case "paymentmessage" :
                $html = $this->_paymentsuccess();
                break;
                default :
                $html =  $this->process($id);
                break;
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }



    function process($id)
    {
        $db     = JFactory::getDBO();
        $app    = JFactory::getApplication();
        $Itemid = JRequest::getInt("Itemid",'0');
        $par    = JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_djclassifieds' );
        $user   = JFactory::getUser();
        $config = JFactory::getConfig();
        $ptype  = JRequest::getVar('ptype');
        $type   = JRequest::getVar('type','');
        $row    = JTable::getInstance('Payments', 'DJClassifiedsTable');

         if($type=='prom_top'){                     
            $query ="SELECT i.* FROM #__djcf_items i "
                    ."WHERE i.id=".$id." LIMIT 1";
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $item = $db->loadObject();
            if(!isset($item)){
                $message = JText::_('COM_DJCLASSIFIEDS_WRONG_AD');
                $redirect="index.php?option=com_djclassifieds&view=items&cid=0";
            }                                

            $row->item_id = $id;
            $row->user_id = $user->id;
            $row->method = $ptype;
            $row->status = 'Start';
            $row->ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $row->price = $par->get('promotion_move_top_price',0);
            $row->type=2;           
            $row->store();

            $amount = $par->get('promotion_move_top_price',0);
            $itemname = $item->name;
            $item_id = $row->id;
            $item_cid = '&cid='.$item->cat_id;          
        }else if($type=='points'){
                $query ="SELECT p.* FROM #__djcf_points p "                
                       ."WHERE p.id=".$id." LIMIT 1";
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $points = $db->loadObject();
                if(!isset($item)){
                    $message = JText::_('COM_DJCLASSIFIEDS_WRONG_POINTS_PACKAGE');
                    $redirect="index.php?option=com_djclassifieds&view=items&cid=0";
                }           
                        $row->item_id = $id;
                        $row->user_id = $user->id;
                        $row->method = $ptype;
                        $row->status = 'Start';
                        $row->ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                        $row->price = $points->price; 
                        $row->type=1;

                    $row->store();      

                $amount = $points->price;
                $itemname = $points->name;
                $item_id = $row->id;
                $item_cid = '';
        }else if($type=='plan'){                        
            $query ="SELECT p.* FROM #__djcf_plans p "
                    ."WHERE p.id=".$id." LIMIT 1";
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $plan = $db->loadObject();
            if(!isset($plan)){
                $message = JText::_('COM_DJCLASSIFIEDS_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN');
                $redirect="index.php?option=com_djclassifieds&view=plans";
            }                                


            $row->item_id = $id;
            $row->user_id = $user->id;
            $row->method = $ptype;
            $row->status = 'Start';
            $row->ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $row->price = $plan->price;
            $row->type=3;           
            $row->store();

            $amount = $plan->price;
            $itemname = $plan->name;
            $item_id = $row->id;
            $item_cid = '';         
        }else{
                $query ="SELECT i.*, c.price as c_price, c.alias as c_alias FROM #__djcf_items i "
                       ."LEFT JOIN #__djcf_categories c ON c.id=i.cat_id "
                       ."WHERE i.id=".$id." LIMIT 1";
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $item = $db->loadObject();
                if(!isset($item)){
                    $message = JText::_('COM_DJCLASSIFIEDS_WRONG_AD');
                    $redirect="index.php?option=com_djclassifieds&view=items&cid=0";
                }

                    $amount = 0;

                    if(strstr($item->pay_type, 'cat')){         
                        $amount += $item->c_price/100; 
                    }

                    if(strstr($item->pay_type, 'type,')){
                        $itype = DJClassifiedsPayment::getTypePrice($item->user_id,$item->type_id);
                        $amount += $itype->price;
                    }

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM #__djcf_days d "
                            ."WHERE d.days=".$item->exp_days." LIMIT 1";
                    $db->setQuery($query);
                    $day = $db->loadObject();


                    if(strstr($item->pay_type, 'duration_renew')){
                        $amount += $day->price_renew;
                    }else if(strstr($item->pay_type, 'duration')){
                        $amount += $day->price;
                    }

                    if(strstr($item->pay_type, 'extra_img_renew')){
                        if($day->img_price_default){
                            $amount += $par->get('img_price_renew','0')*$item->extra_images_to_pay;
                        }else{
                            $amount += $day->img_price_renew*$item->extra_images_to_pay;
                        }
                    }else if(strstr($item->pay_type, 'extra_img')){
                        if($day->img_price_default){
                            $amount += $par->get('img_price','0')*$item->extra_images_to_pay;
                        }else{
                            $amount += $day->img_price*$item->extra_images_to_pay;
                        }
                    }

                    if(strstr($item->pay_type, 'extra_chars_renew')){
                        if($day->char_price_default){
                            $amount += $par->get('desc_char_price_renew','0')*$item->extra_chars_to_pay;
                        }else{
                            $amount += $day->char_price_renew*$item->extra_chars_to_pay;
                        }
                    }else if(strstr($item->pay_type, 'extra_chars')){
                        if($day->char_price_default){
                            $amount += $par->get('desc_char_price','0')*$item->extra_chars_to_pay;
                        }else{
                            $amount += $day->char_price*$item->extra_chars_to_pay;
                        }
                    }                   


                    $query = "SELECT p.* FROM #__djcf_promotions p "
                        ."WHERE p.published=1 ORDER BY p.id ";
                    $db->setQuery($query);
                    $promotions=$db->loadObjectList();
                    foreach($promotions as $prom){
                        if(strstr($item->pay_type, $prom->name)){   
                            $amount += $prom->price; 
                        }   
                    }

                    /*$query = 'DELETE FROM #__djcf_payments WHERE item_id= "'.$id.'" ';
                    $db->setQuery($query);
                    $db->query();


                    $query = 'INSERT INTO #__djcf_payments ( item_id,user_id,method,  status)' .
                            ' VALUES ( "'.$id.'" ,"'.$user->id.'","'.$ptype.'" ,"Start" )'
                            ;
                    $db->setQuery($query);
                    $db->query();*/

                        $row->item_id = $id;
                        $row->user_id = $user->id;
                        $row->method = $ptype;
                        $row->status = 'Start';
                        $row->ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                        $row->price = $amount;
                        $row->type=0;

                    $row->store();                  



                $itemname = $item->name;
                $item_id = $row->id;
                $item_cid = '&cid='.$item->cat_id;
                $item_slug = $item->id.':'.$item->alias;
                $cat_slug = $item->cat_id.':'.$item->c_alias;
            }
        /*
        $query ="SELECT i.*, c.price as c_price, c.alias as c_alias FROM #__djcf_items i "
               ."LEFT JOIN #__djcf_categories c ON c.id=i.cat_id "
               ."WHERE i.id=".$id." LIMIT 1";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $item = $db->loadObject();
        if(!isset($item)){
            $message = JText::_('COM_DJCLASSIFIEDS_WRONG_AD');
            $redirect="index.php?option=com_djclassifieds&view=items&cid=0";
        }

            $query = 'DELETE FROM #__djcf_payments WHERE item_id= "'.$id.'" ';
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->query();


            $query = 'INSERT INTO #__djcf_payments ( item_id,user_id,method,  status)' .
                    ' VALUES ( "'.$id.'" ,"'.$user->id.'","'.$ptype.'" ,"Start" )'
                    ;
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->query();


        $amount = 0;

            if(strstr($item->pay_type, 'cat')){         
                $amount += $item->c_price/100; 
            }
            if(strstr($item->pay_type, 'duration_renew')){          
                $query = "SELECT d.price_renew FROM #__djcf_days d "
                ."WHERE d.days=".$item->exp_days;
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $amount += $db->loadResult();
            }else if(strstr($item->pay_type, 'duration')){          
                $query = "SELECT d.price FROM #__djcf_days d "
                ."WHERE d.days=".$item->exp_days;
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $amount += $db->loadResult();
            }

            $query = "SELECT p.* FROM #__djcf_promotions p "
                ."WHERE p.published=1 ORDER BY p.id ";
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $promotions=$db->loadObjectList();
            foreach($promotions as $prom){
                if(strstr($item->pay_type, $prom->name)){   
                    $amount += $prom->price; 
                }   
            }   
            */                              

            if($user->id){              
                /*$mailto = $user->email;           
                $mailfrom = $app->getCfg( 'mailfrom' );             
                $fromname=$config->get('config.sitename').' - '.str_ireplace('administrator/', '', JURI::base());

                $subject = JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_INFRORMATIONS').' '.$config->get('config.sitename');
                $m_message = JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_INFRORMATIONS').' '.$config->get('config.sitename')."<br /><br />";

                if($type=='points'){
                    $m_message .= JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_POINTS_PACKAGE').': '.$itemname."<br /><br />";
                }else{
                    $m_message .= JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_AD_NAME').': '.$itemname."<br /><br />";   
                }

                $m_message .= JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_PRICE_TO_PAY').': '.$amount.' '.$par->get('unit_price','')."<br /><br />";
                $m_message .= JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_PAY_INFORMATION').': <br /><br />'.JHTML::_('content.prepare',nl2br($this->params["pay_info"]))."<br /><br />";

                if($type==''){
                    $u = JURI::getInstance( JURI::base() );
                    $link=  $u->getHost().JRoute::_(DJClassifiedsSEO::getItemRoute($item_slug,$cat_slug));                      
                    $m_message .=JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_AD_LINK').': <a href="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a><br /><br />';
                    $m_message .=JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_AD_ID').': '.$id.'<br /><br />';                
                }
                $m_message .=JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_ID').': '.$item_id;

                $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
                $mailer->sendMail($mailfrom, $fromname, $mailto, $subject, $m_message,$mode=1);*/

                $payment_info = array();
                $payment_info['id'] = $item_id;
                $payment_info['itemname'] = $itemname;
                $payment_info['amount'] = DJClassifiedsTheme::priceFormat($amount,$par->get('unit_price',''));
                $payment_info['info'] = $this->params["pay_info"];

                DJClassifiedsNotify::notifyUserPayment($type,$id,$payment_info);

            }


            echo '<div id="dj-classifieds" class="clearfix">';
                echo '<table width="98%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="paymentdetails first">';
                echo '<tr><td class="td_title"><h2>'.$this->params["payment_method"].'</h2></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td class="td_pdetails">';
                        echo '<div class="pd_row">';
                            if($type=='points'){
                                echo '<span class="djcfpay_label">'.JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_POINTS_PACKAGE').':</span>';
                            }else{
                                echo '<span class="djcfpay_label">'.JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_AD_NAME').':</span>';
                            }
                            echo '<span class="djcfpay_value">'.$itemname.'</span>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<div class="pd_row">';
                            echo '<span class="djcfpay_label">'.JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_PRICE_TO_PAY').':</span>';
                            echo '<span class="djcfpay_value">'.$amount.' '.$par->get('unit_price','').'</span>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<div class="pd_row">';
                            if($type=='points'){
                                echo '<span class="djcfpay_label">'.JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_POINTS_ID').':</span>';
                            }else{                              
                                echo '<span class="djcfpay_label">'.JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_AD_ID').':</span>';
                            }

                            echo '<span class="djcfpay_value">'.$id.'</span>';
                        echo '</div>';                      
                        echo '<div class="pd_row">';
                            echo '<span class="djcfpay_label">'.JText::_('PLG_DJCFBANKTRANSFER_PAYMENT_PAY_INFORMATION').': </span><br /><br />';
                            echo '<span class="djcfpay_value">'.JHTML::_('content.prepare',nl2br($this->params["pay_info"])).'</span>';                         
                        echo '</div>';  
                    echo '</td></tr>';                          
                echo '</table>';
            echo '</div>';

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say. I doubt that I'm the only one.

Comment: You have bought a GPL licensed code o_O ? And if you have bought a code, why not ask whoever you sold it ?

Comment: In such situations of misunderstand what you need you may be helped using illustrations using screen shots of what you have or a simple drawing image. All what I have understood, there is missing field in your report.

Comment: Yes i bought GPL code, due to regural update...it is joomla extension.

Comment: Yes i bought GPL code, due to regural update...it is joomla payed extension I am not good in php , so i want to add in these page userID in all 3 reports.  I will figure it on my one / Garf365 if you looked in code there are ID... and some like you should see when code generate report with pointsplanID, adsID, paymentID , and tell me how to ad one more field with userID. It is easy when you know / i was honest and wrote what i did and what i do not know, i was learnin pascal languege 30 years ago...i was needing minor help...